# how to filter on specific rows of an array JS

Tags: javascript

I have a simple array, I want to make a `search functionality` on this array. I have an input where I enter data to search. But the search goes through all the lines of the object, and I need only lines `name` and `day`.

How can the code below be modified to implement this functionality, do you have a better option for this?

```
const data =[
 {
  name: 'name',
  day: 'monday',
  year: '2023',
  user:'user13421'
 },
 {
  name: 'name1',
  day: 'monday1',
  year: '20231',
  user:'user134211'
 }
]


let filtered;
  const onSearchF = (keyword) => {
    filtered = data.filter((entry) =>
      Object.values(entry).some(
        (val) =>
          typeof val === "string" &&
          val.toLowerCase().includes(keyword.toLowerCase())
      )
    );
  };
```

Comment: Than do not loop all the entry values, check only `entry.name` and `entry.day`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find object by id in an array of JavaScript objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364150/find-object-by-id-in-an-array-of-javascript-objects)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const data =[
 {
  name: 'name',
  day: 'monday',
  year: '2023',
  user:'user13421'
 },
 {
  name: 'name1',
  day: 'monday1',
  year: '20231',
  user:'user134211'
 }
]


const filterKeys = ['name', 'day'];
let filtered;

  const onSearchF = (keyword) => {
    const lowerKeyword = keyword.toLowerCase();
    filtered = data.filter((entry) => {
        return filterKeys.some(key => entry[key].toLowerCase().includes(lowerKeyword));
    });
  };
```

I would advise, if possible, instead of modifying external variable, to return filtered array, like this:

```
const data =[
 {
  name: 'name',
  day: 'monday',
  year: '2023',
  user:'user13421'
 },
 {
  name: 'name1',
  day: 'monday1',
  year: '20231',
  user:'user134211'
 }
]


const filterKeys = ['name', 'day'];

  const onSearchF = (keyword) => {
    const lowerKeyword = keyword.toLowerCase();
    return data.filter((entry) => {
        return filterKeys.some(key => entry[key].toLowerCase().includes(lowerKeyword));
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just search the two properties only. This works:

```
const onSearchF = (keyword) => {
    filtered = data.filter((entry) => (
        entry.day.toLowerCase().includes(keyword.toLowerCase()) ||
        entry.name.toLowerCase().includes(keyword.toLowerCase())
    ));
};
```

If you want to be fancier and not repeat those two lines of code you can do this:

```
let filtered;
const onSearchF = (keyword) => {
    filtered = data.filter((entry) => (
        [entry.day, entry.name].some(val => val.toLowerCase().includes(keyword.toLowerCase()) )
    ));
};
```

but I'm not sure it's better tho